# How to separate PostgreSQL data for different Mac users?

Tags: macos, postgresql

When installing PostgreSQL on MacOS you need to create a data folder where it will store details about users, dbs and privileges, but this data is globally available.
Is there a way to separate this based on Mac users?

This way:

- When logging in with UserA, PostgreSQL will only instantiate/see DB_A1 and DB_A2 and PostgreSQL users defined only for UserA's PostgreSQL instance.
- When logging in with UserB, PostgreSQL will only instantiate/see DB_B1 and DB_B2 and PostgreSQL users defined only for UserB's PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: All mac users can sudo, right?  If you can sudo, you ultimately have full control over everything on the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i understand what you are saying, but i am more interested in having different DBs (or data databases) for different OS users and have them loaded on login.

Comment: You might be able to manage something like that with `pg_hba.conf`.  Create postgres users mapping to mac OS users, and assign the users ownership of appropriate databases.  It won't be secure, but it may be convenient. perhaps http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT

Comment: Frank, only users authorized by /etc/sudoers can sudo, like on every other unix. If the account is created through the GUI as a standard account, then it will not be able to sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to my somewhat rusty knowledge about PostgreSQL your intention would lead to start a postmaster process for every user on his/her own reserved port. Although this is possible, it smells like smoke from administration hell (not counting the overhead of a fat RDBMS process reserved for a single user spending most of the time waiting). Positively expressed I propose considering one of the following options:

- Add a line to `pg_hba.conf` like `local all sameuser all md5` to allow all local users to only access their personal databaase (named like the user). Access to system data may be further restricted depending on the actual PostgreSQL version you're using (it's best to consult the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/) in this case).
- Depending on the amount of data if concurrent access was not a critical must-have (which seems to be the case here) switch to sqlite3; it's performant, data sits in a single file, access is provided by a library instead of a full fledged RDBMS background process armada, and it comes ready to use with every Mac OS X.

Comment: sqlite is out of the question for the current needs.
If i understand correctly what you are saying, means creating a postgres user for UserA and another one for UserB. 
I am actually looking to setup 2 different environments, one that is instantiated when UserA logs, in and the other for UserB, each one having its own pgusers and dbs, which is why I was aking for a solution to define the datadb (initial db) separate for each os user.

Comment: After skimming over the actual documentation it still seems not to be possible to grant a role (users and groups have been replaced by the role concept since version 8 or so) the privilege to create new roles unless this user has superuser rights and therefore allowing her to access all DBs of the installation This leaves my first approach from above the only path to go. Probably it's worth then to start a user's postgres processes not until he logs in. This may be done with additional config parameters like in `postmaster -c data_directory=<user specific data path goes here>`. Does that help?